# ZF Tool does not show version details or module list

Tags: php, zend-framework

On command prompt the outputs are as follows :

```
VARADA@THOSHIBA c:\xampp
# php -v
PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 23:48:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

VARADA@THOSHIBA c:\xampp
# php composer.phar show --installed
zendframework/zend-code           2.2.5              provides facilities t...
zendframework/zend-config         2.2.5              provides a nested obj...
zendframework/zend-console        2.2.5
zendframework/zend-eventmanager   2.2.5
zendframework/zend-file           2.2.5
zendframework/zend-filter         2.2.5              provides a set of com...
zendframework/zend-form           2.2.5
zendframework/zend-inputfilter    2.2.5
zendframework/zend-json           2.2.5              provides convenience ...
zendframework/zend-loader         2.2.5
zendframework/zend-math           2.2.5
zendframework/zend-modulemanager  2.2.5
zendframework/zend-mvc            2.2.5
zendframework/zend-serializer     2.2.5              provides an adapter b...
zendframework/zend-servicemanager 2.2.5
zendframework/zend-stdlib         2.2.5
zendframework/zend-text           2.2.5
zendframework/zend-validator      2.2.5              provides a set of com...
zendframework/zend-version        2.2.5
zendframework/zend-view           2.2.5              provides a system of ...
zendframework/zftool              dev-master d73bf6f Utility module for Ze...

VARADA@THOSHIBA c:\xampp
# zf.php version

VARADA@THOSHIBA c:\xampp
#
```

I am not getting any error or o/p for zf.php version. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but the syntax to display the version of Zend (1) is:

```
zf.php show version
```

I hope it will help

Comment: It also shows nothing..

C:\xampp>zf.php show version

C:\xampp>
this is the o/p

Comment: In your folder where zf.php, you must have a zf.bat.<br>
If yes, try `zf.bat show version`